# Tridion Logging in DEBUG mode- Unable to turn off

Tags: 2011, logging

One of our website uses DD4t with Broker DB for storing data. We have observed the behavior where website logs everything in DEBUG mode even we specified WARN\INFO as debug mode.

Daily it would log up to 12GB of log(cd_core). We tried restarting IIS and replacing the logback.xml with another sites logback.xml file. Still the site logs in DEBUG mode.

What could be causing this behavior.

I am trying to fix the issue now as disk space is getting consumed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default logback configuration for Tridion does make use of automatic reloading, so any changes in logback.xml will not be picked up until the application restarts. In other words, you'd have to replace logback.xml and *then* restart IIS.

UPDATE: I was wrong. The default logback.xml has `scan="true"` - [without a scan period this will default to a minute](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#autoScan).

If that's not it, then I'd be wondering whether you're picking up the correct logback.xml. As you are using IIS, and are therefore on windows, you could use Sysinternals procmon to log access to all files called logback.xml on your system. Tridion configuraiton files need to be in bin/config relative to the web application root. If they aren't there, your system may still work, for example if you have configuration files available system-wide. Check your TRIDION_HOME environment variable.

Comment: We have updated the logback.xml and restarted the app pool and website. Still it was loading\logging

Comment: I have completely removed logback.xml from bin\config. Restarted application(App pool\website). Logging Stopped.

Then added back logback.xml to bin\config with logging as WARN and restarted application(App pool\website). I have been monitoring for 15 minutes till now no issue is seen.

Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Tridion's own logging (which is configured through the logback.xml, see other answers) DD4T has its own logging mechanism. Or actually two: one based on Log4Net and the other based on Microsoft's Enterprise Library.

You can tell which logging framework you're using by looking at the appSetting with key DD4T.LoggerClass. For Log4Net, for example, the key should look like this:

```
<add key="DD4T.LoggerClass" value="DD4T.LogWrappers.Log4Net.Log4NetLogger, DD4T.LogWrappers.Log4Net"/>
```

Follow the instructions of the logging framework, to configure the loglevel.

Log4Net: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html.

Microsoft Enterprise Library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440731%28v=pandp.60%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Chances are that you have a logger configured to log in Debug, and perhaps you're just changing the top log level? Individual logger configurations for specific classes will override the main log level.

Also, you *can* configure logback to reload its configuration without restarting by adding a `scanPeriod` attribute to the configuration:

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="5 minutes">
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you share your logback.xml file,

- do some basic debugging like change file name to ensure that log is being created by the config file you are referring. with below line you can create log file hourly.

> ${log.folder}/cd_monitor.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log

- also double check other modules like Cache Channel service etc are not creating that particular log.

Comment: I have moved the logs from c:\Tridion\logs to c:\Tridoin\websitename and it started logging to the location new location in DEBUG mode, even though I had INFO set in logbak.xml